# Способы получения постов из группы VK

Tags: vkontakte-api, python-3.5

Цель:
Получить новый пост как можно скорее.

Я использую цикл и wall.get с паузой в 1 секунду, но этот набор иногда нарывается на ошибки типо "слишком частые запросы", так вот, есть ли иной способ получения постов?

P.s. я не являюсь администратором этого сообщества. Это открытое сообщество.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то наверное нужно смотреть в сторону https://vk.com/dev/groups.setCallbackSettings и на https://vk.com/dev/callback_api Согласно документации должны приходить уведомления о различных новых событиях

Comment: @pincher1519 автор вопроса не является администратором сообщества, как он и указал. Воспользоваться callback api он, соответственно, не сможет.ъ

Comment: @PeterSamokhin, это не исключает возможность получения ключа доступа сообщества :-) Хотя я что-то не заметил этой приписки, спасибо за уточнение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вам нужно смотреть в сторону [Long Poll](https://vk.com/dev/using_longpoll) сервера.

Comment: Разве он не работает только с сообщениями?

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [документации](https://vk.com/dev/data_limits), на этот метод наложены ограничения по количеству вызовов:

> wall.get — 5000 вызовов в сутки.

Скорее всего, вы превышаете лимит. А подробными и соответствующими действительности ответами с ошибками ВК никогда не славились.

> При указании версии 5.74 возвращается новая ошибка: 29 Rate limit reached.

Видимо, используемая вами версия ниже 5.74, и поэтому вы получаете другую ошибку. Если же вы не уверены, что точно раз в секунду (и не чаще) обращаетесь к этому методу, то перепроверьте, возможно проблема ещё и в вашем коде.

Comment: Код подобен этому:
`while True:
    try:
        wall.get()
        ....
        time.sleep(1)
    except .... :
        ....
        time.sleep(2)`

был на версии 5.6х
Сейчас на версии 5.72 и ничего не изменилось, НО суть вопроса не в ошибках, а в способах получения постов, если отличных от такого нет, то очень жаль...

Comment: @ИванКакуркин можно использовать `Streaming API` от ВК, только без "полного доступа" от него нет толку, а полный доступ можно только через поддержку получить (далеко не факт, что вам его дадут). Так что да, в принципе, другого способа сейчас нет.